# DNS: How to redirect a domain to a different domain's subdomain?

Tags: http, redirect, dns, subdomain

I would like to use `subdomain.example.com` as a server for `example2.com`. Is that possible?

Right now I have this, but it's not working:

```
   --------------------------------------------------------
   hostname                | priority | value        | ttl
   --------------------------------------------------------
   subdomain.example.com   | A        | ip_address   | 3600
   subdomain               | CNAME    | example.com  | 3600
   --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Make it point to the same IP in DNS and add the hostname to the web server configuration.

Comment: +1, though more setup might be required if the web server is using virtual hosts (and/or the content served has hardcoded absolute URLs).

Comment: what do you mean by `and add the hostname to the web server configuration `?

Comment: @CodeCaster I updated my question, do you think that my DNS configuration is good? It's not working but maybe because my server is not configured well.

Comment: @Adam did you figure it out? :)